# Python misreads serial data

Tags: python, arduino, readline

I'm reading serial data in vPython from Arduino and getting data errors during readline.  Sometimes it reads two lines in a row, and this time it missed a comma as I tried to show in the photo.  Code is below.

What causes this?

[img]http://i.imgur.com/cAw7De1.png

Python code:

```
arduinoSerialData=serial.Serial('/dev/cu.usbmodem1421',115200) 
while (1==1): #loops forever
     rate (30) # tells vPython to run this loop (times/sec)
     while(arduinoSerialData.inWaiting()==0): 
      pass #do nothing

     sensorCallInfo = arduinoSerialData.readline()
     print sensorCallInfo 

     dataNums = sensorCallInfo.split(',') 

     x1 = float(dataNums[0]) 
     y1 = float(dataNums[1])
     z1 = float(dataNums[2])
     sysCal = int(dataNums[3]) 
     gyroCal = int(dataNums[4])
     accelCal = int(dataNums[5])
     magCal = int(dataNums[6]) 

     print x1, y1, z1, sysCal, gyroCal, accelCal, magCal
     print
     print
```

Arduino Code:

```
#include <Wire.h>
#include <Adafruit_Sensor.h>
#include <Adafruit_BNO055.h>
#include <utility/imumaths.h>

#define BNO055_SAMPLERATE_DELAY_MS (50)
imu::Vector<3> linearAccel; 
uint8_t systemcal, gyrocal, accelcal, magcal = 0; 
Adafruit_BNO055 bno = Adafruit_BNO055(55);

void setup(void)
{
  Serial.begin(115200);
  while (!Serial); 

  if (!bno.begin()) //checks for sensor to start
  {
    Serial.print("No sensor detected.  Check wiring or I2C address.");
    while (1);
  }

  bno.setExtCrystalUse(true);
}

void loop(void)
{
  bno.getCalibration(&systemcal, &gyrocal, &accelcal, &magcal); 
  linearAccel = bno.getVector(Adafruit_BNO055::VECTOR_LINEARACCEL); 

  outputForPython();
  delay(BNO055_SAMPLERATE_DELAY_MS);
}


void outputForPython()
{
  Serial.print(linearAccel.x());  Serial.print(",");
  Serial.print(linearAccel.y());  Serial.print(",");
  Serial.print(linearAccel.z());  Serial.print(",");
  Serial.print(systemcal, DEC);   Serial.print(",");
  Serial.print(gyrocal, DEC);     Serial.print(",");
  Serial.print(accelcal, DEC);    Serial.print(",");
  Serial.print(magcal, DEC);      Serial.println("");
}
```

Comment: does this happen if you set up your serial port to run at 9600 baud?

Comment: what's most likely happening is the switching of the serial port is too fast, so your getting an improper read on one of the edges ... https://www.sparkfun.com/tutorials/215

Comment: This happens at 9600 baud as well.  I'll look up the tutorial, thanks for the link.  I'll try a new cable as well and see if that's the problem.  I think you're right about the noise because sometimes the last read before the error is of two lines as one line, meaning the reading error is slightly different each time.

Comment: sounds good ... if you're really into this hobby, buying a 100.00 usb digital logic analyzer can be rally handy, especially when you get around to using an SPI interface ... i own this one https://www.saleae.com (which is top google search), it's quite nice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are most likely getting noise on the line. You can try and adjust your baud rate or try a different cable. Sparkfun has some good details on the issue: https://www.sparkfun.com/tutorials/215 -- an alternate approach is to use ethernet  for communications instead of serial depending on the reliability you need. I think you will have more success at a lower baud rate.